# RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper - Custom View

Tags: android, swipe, android-recyclerview

I am trying to have a custom view (or image) appear when swiping left/right.

I'm close to having it working, however I'm having issues with using a custom image.

The effect I'm going for is similar to this: [RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper swipe remove animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418905/recyclerview-itemtouchhelper-swipe-remove-animation)

See what's happening below. It's warping the image as the swipe happens:

[image]

Below is what my code looks like:

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
        float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;

        Paint p = new Paint();
        if (dX > 0) {
            Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.test_check);
            d.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), (int) dX, itemView.getBottom());
            d.draw(c);

            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        } 

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
}
```

How can I keep the image static while continuing to draw the background color? Is it possible to even use an Android view instead of an image? Similar to this: https://github.com/wdullaer/SwipeActionAdapter

Answer (score 5):

You can prepare your recycler view item layout to include the check symbol `ImageView` and maybe another blank view with just the background color. You should also move all the swipeable content into a nested layout. Assign a reference to the swipeable content in your view holder. Then just call `setTranslationX` on your swipeable content in `onChildDraw`, like:

```
((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).swipeableContent.setTranslationX(dX);
```

### **Update With Source Code Example:**

Recycler view item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/recycler_view_item_height"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <!-- background color view -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/purple" />

    <!-- check symbol image view -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/check_symbol_width"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/check_symbol" />

    <!-- swipeable content container -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeable_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- here goes your swipeable content -->
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

View holder class:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // Swipeable content container.
    LinearLayout swipeableContent;

    /*
     ... here goes other sub-views
    */

    public ExpenseViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // bind swipeable content container view
        swipeableContent = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipeable_content);

        /*
         ... bind other sub-views
        */
    }
}
```

ItemTouchHelper.Callback subclass:

```
class ItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(final Canvas c,
                            final RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                            final float dX,
                            final float dY,
                            final int actionState,
                            final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
            // translate by swipe amount, 
            // the check symbol and the background will stay in place
            ((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).swipeableContent.setTranslationX(dX);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hmm should I be hiding that swiepable content by default then showing it? otherwise it will show on the card. Are there any examples of this showing the XML view?

Comment: @aherrick i have updated my answer with more source code, hope it helps.

Comment: @Kustal - in this example how will the swipeable content area be hidden until swiping? also I am using a cardview for the action item layout. thanks!

Comment: why would you want to hide the swipeable area? the area below that (check symbol and the purple background) will be hidden until the swipe begins and reveals it, as you've explained.

Comment: Thanks for the additional code, but I'm still not having any luck with this. Would you be able to create a simple sample project demonstrating your example? Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you got solution or not and also not sure whether you have seen this library or not.

I have try [Android-SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) library for one of my project and [SwipeMenuListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) for another project for something similar requirements.

Both are working fine in their place. You should give a try on that and check how it should work for your requirement.

Let me know if you need more help from me.

Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: thanks for the thoughts I have looked into these but they are custom libraries. I was looking for an option using the base swipe features with new recyclerview

Comment: @aherrick great to hear that you are trying to make your own code to work like that. You should get some reference from that library. I guess that gone be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `(int)dX` in d.setBounds() to any `integer` you want.

eg:

```
d.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), 50, itemView.getBottom());
```